# How do I add another activity in the main .java file

Tags: android, eclipse, button

This is my code in my main java file. How would i make another button to connect with the activity. please tell me if i am not expressing this well enough. I just need to add another button into the main java file. I already have an activity in the manifest and a class for it, i just need to put another block of code into the main java file. The id of the button is p40, the name of the xml layout is p40.xml, the class is called p40.java and the activity is called p40. This is my code at the moment:

```
package com.duncan.hello.world;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.duncan.hello.world.R;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button aButton;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }});
}
}
```

Comment: To add another button, do the same thing that you did to add the first. Just add another one to your layout. And inflate it in your main.java file.

Comment: can you tell me which block of code it is though??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
// This code is copied from your code as is 
// to have a reference point as well as this is also
// code for adding click listener to button which you
// need to handle click and then do what you want.
// In this case you are launching an Activity
// Block of code you already have to use STARTS
aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }});
// Block of code you already have to use ENDS

// This code is added for newButton which looks similar to above block
Button newButton
newButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, AnOtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }});
```

You have to add another `button1` in `layout/main.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that there are 2 possibilities to you make that:
The first ones, You have to separate what is "activity.xml" and "Activity.class", in XML you'll declare and configure you button, in .java you'll assign that wanna be implemented. (with /out intent's..)

The second onws, you have to declare you button in you .java.

I'll show you:
activity.xml

```
<Button android:id="@+button/test" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="First Button"/>
<Button android:id="@+button/test2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Second Button"/>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Activity.java

..

```
Button first = (Button)findViewById(R.button.test);
Button second = (Button)findViewById(R.button.test2);

first.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do Something guy
    }});

second.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do diferent something
    }});
```

..

I wish I helped.
Regards

Comment: what should i put in the //do something guy and //do diferent something?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Android Developers Blog: UI framework changes in Android 1.6](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html)

Specifically the "Easier click listeners" section at the bottom.

"With Android 1.6, none of this is necessary. All you have to do is declare a public method in your Activity to handle the click (the method must have one View argument):"

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        // Do stuff
    } }
```

"And then reference this method from your XML layout:"

```
<Button android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

It just makes the code a little bit cleaner.

Comment: thank you A LOT for that, i had no idea it would be that simple. :) but that spot where it says //do stuff what should i put???

Comment: Not sure if that last sentence was a joke. But if not it would depend on what you're trying to achieve in your app. 'myClickHandler' is tied to the button being pressed so you just add whatever code is needed for when a user presses that button. Ideally you would have a handler for each button. You could reuse your handlers and check for which View was passed in as a parameter, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you have a valid reason for doing it that way.